# Get the value of class in TD JQuery click

Tags: jquery

I want to get the current value from a class from a td in table

script

```
 $(".edit").click(function() {
        // $("#cost").modal();
        id = $('tr').find('td.cost').text();
        alert(id);
    });
```

table

```
 foreach($val as $val)
<tr>
  <td class="cost">{{ $val->cost}}</td>
  <td>{{$val->value }} </td>
  <td><a class="edit"></a></td>
```

endforeach

I tried

```
 $(".edit").click(function() {
        // $("#cost").modal();
        id = $('tr').find('td.cost').text();
        alert(id);
    });
```

but it will get all values like 12,23,23 (assuming there are three ids fetch from db)

Comment: Instead of `id = $('tr').find('td.cost').text();` ... try..`var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.cost').text();`

Comment: Which do you need, a value or a value set?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.cost').text();
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/79rhptLz/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Have your function defined in javascript and call it from the HTML using an onclick event, rather than binding it from your javascript file.

eg

```
foreach($val as $val) 
    <tr>
        <td class="cost">{{ $val->cost}}</td>  
        <td>{{$val->value }} </td>   
        <td>
            <a class="edit" onclick="myFunction(this)"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

and then in javacript define a function like the following

```
function myFunction(item) {
    var text = $(item).text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use siblings

```
$(".edit").click(function() {
        // $("#cost").modal();
        id = $(this).siblings('td.cost').text();
        alert(id);
    });
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/w6ea9hnn/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :
Example :
HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cost">12</td>
    <td>hello</td>
    <td><a class="edit">edit</a></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="cost">15</td>
    <td>hi </td>
    <td><a class="edit">edit</a></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="cost">20</td>
    <td>hey</td>
    <td><a class="edit">edit</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(".edit").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.cost').text();
  alert(id);
});
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03dnm95m/) example